# Understanding ていたこともあり

Tags: grammar

> マスコットの職分は極論すれば『部隊にいること』だけだが、フレデリカはシン達が特士校に在籍している時から一足先に試験部隊に**配属されていたこともあり**、研究開発班や部隊指揮官との連絡調整役を積極的にかってでている。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

A girl called フレデリカ is acting as a mascot in the army.

Does the bold part use the construction 〜たことがある to refer to a past experience? If not, how should I understand the たこともあり?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this こともある does not refer to one's past experience ("She has (once) ..."). This is a way of describing a (partial) reason. It's used like this:

> 雨が降っていたこともあり、買い物には行かなかった。
> Because of the rain, (among other reasons,) I did not go shopping.

See:

- [〜こともあって｜日本語能力試験　JLPT　N１文法](https://www.edewakaru.com/archives/26539117.html)
- [JLPT N1 Grammar こともあって (koto mo atte)](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-koto-mo-atte-meaning/)